# How use pnp-sp search in sharepoint for exact match string?

Tags: string, search, sharepoint, match

I want to find all document, file ecc in my site sharepoint with in input a string,
I have used

```
   var searchFilters = {
        Querytext: "Hello",
        TrimDuplicates: false 
   }
    sp.search(searchFilters).then((r: SearchResults) => {

        console.log(r.PrimarySearchResults);

    });
```

But i want that the result have exact match path string, not that start or and with the querytext string, 
respecting upper and lower case

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
querytext='Filename:searchkeyword.* AND ContentClass:STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary'
```

[Keyword Query Language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference)